# How to set an environment variable in application.yml - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, properties, yaml, mockserver

I'm working on a spring boot application and I'm writing some tests which use MockServer.
In order to not have all the requests to the mock servers displayed in the logs, I have to set the environment variable mockserver.logLevel to OFF.
When I do it via command line, it works perfectly :

```
mvn clean install -Dmockserver.logLevel="OFF"
```

but when I try to do it in my application.yml, it doesn't work.
I've tried the following :

```
mockserver:
    log-level: OFF
```

---

```
mockserver:
    loglevel: OFF
```

---

```
mockserver:
    logLevel: OFF
```

---

```
logging:
  level:
    org.mockserver: OFF
```

But none of these work.
I guess I don't write it correctly in the application.yml but I can't figure out the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way by adding it directly into the pom.xml as a system property variable in the concerned plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven-failsafe-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <mockserver.logLevel>OFF</mockserver.logLevel>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

an another 'wiring' solution:

```java
@Configuration
public class MockServerConfiguration {
    ... 
    public MockServerConfiguration(@Value("${mockserver.logLevel}") String mockserverLogLevel) {
        if (Objects.isNull(System.getProperty("mockserver.logLevel"))) {
            System.setProperty("mockserver.logLevel", mockserverLogLevel);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```